# Javascript: passing text from li item to a function onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I'm making a chat application in js/java. It has a list of online users off to the side, and I wanted the users' names to be clickable so that if you click them, you can send that person a private message. Everything is working and I tested the code below to make sure that clicking a user's name triggers the function (button()).

What I need it to do: in the function updateChat(), line id("userlist"), it needs to be able to pass the text from the list item that was clicked on to the function button(). I need to set that username as a variable so that the next time that user sends a message, its sent to that one user and not broadcasted.

It won't let me pass "user" as an argument and I'm not sure how to pass that text along. Thank you

```
var privmsg = "";
function updateChat(msg) { // Update chat-panel and list of connected users
    let data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    id("chat").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", data.userMessage);
    id("userlist").innerHTML = data.userlist.map(user => "<li role=\"presentation\" 
        class=\"link\" value=\"thing\" onclick=\"button(user)\"><span>" + user + "</span>
        </li>").join("");
}

function button(newuser){
    String(newuser);
    privmsg = newuser;
}
```

Comment: See the issue? `onclick="button(foobar)"`

Comment: @epascarello I don't really im sorry >.< I'm new to javascript. It worked with this exact syntax until I added the argument to button()

Comment: It is looking for the variable foobar, not the string foobar.

Comment: @epascarello you cant pass a string as an argument? I'm a c++ programmer I'm kind of lost with this.. could i do var USER = user and then pass USER? or cast user to type var? idk if you can do typecasting in js

Comment: You are writing a string out to the page. When it is rendered the code thinks foobar is a variable becuase you did not put quotes around it to make a string. Actually I am wrong in this case because you assume user is defined, but it is not. `onclick=\"button('" + user + "')\"><span>" + user +`

Comment: @epascarello I changed it to onclick="button("user")" and it underlines user and says "expression statement is not assignment or call"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need concat the `user` as `string` argument to the called function like

```
button('" + user + "')
```

Here is example snippet

```js
var users = ["A", "B", "C"];



document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML = users.map(function (user) {
        return "<li role=\"presentation\" \n        class=\"link\" value=\"thing\" onclick=\"button('" + user + "')\"><span>\" + " + user + " + \"</span</li>";
});       
        
        
function button(newuser){
    alert(newuser)
    privmsg = newuser;
}
```

```html
<ul id="userlist"></ul>
```